# Can I use the crushed remains of my existing concrete driveway as a base for supporting geocell with gravel as my new driveway?

Tags: concrete

I plan to break up old concrete driveway into "1-3" pieces and mix with "57" gravel where needed and use this as the sub base to place a geocell filled with new gravel as the driveway. My main objective is to keep the crushed concrete as permeable as possible. I can vacuum out most of the concrete dust created by the demolition. Overall will this old crushed concrete serve as a viable sub base with good permeability?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems with your plan.  If your geocell is 2" tall the only issue is you'll potentially have to place the 3" pieces carefully to keep them shy of the surface.  The 3/4" crush will also have a certain look to it so having some 1-3" pieces of concrete with defined sides is also going to have a visual impact on your installation.  Depending on where you are located you can order 3/4" crush that is made from recycled concrete so that might blend better with the concrete you are planning on recycling.

How are you going to make these 1-3" pieces?  I broke up 40' of concrete sidewalk into pieces that were easier to manage and it was a lot of work.  I can't imagine trying to turn them into 1-3" pieces.

Comment: Rent one of [these](https://aimixcrusherplant.com/concrete-crusher/amp/) ?  :)

Comment: I had a pool demolished.  The crusher was big, ie it had a cab, it took three weeks to produce 8 inch pieces and the neighbors were UNhappy.  I think the last paragraph is key.